# image Capture use case not properly working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax

I have started android studio a week ago to make an simple camera app using cameraX as the first step in to android app development . there is this android [developer forum](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#0) that I found useful. I followed the each step as described and tried my best to understand the cameraX implementations. even though no errors are showing the app gets build seamlessly but the image capture does not seems to be working .but there are couple of logcat error messages, but of course I do not understand any of them.
app permissions for camera and external storages are all included in the AndroidMinifest.xml file.
dependencies are also included in the build.gradle.kts file
"take photo" buttons ID is imageCaptureButton.

logcat E massages looks like these.

```
set:488 set: Unset optional value from type SMPTE2086
 IMGMapper com.example.cameraxapp    E  set:488 set: Unset optional value from type SMPTE2086
 IMGMapper com.example.cameraxapp    E  set:488 set: Unset optional value from type CTA861_3 set
```

the MainActivity.kt file looks like this

```
package com.example.cameraxapp

import android.Manifest
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture
import androidx.camera.video.Recorder
import androidx.camera.video.Recording
import androidx.camera.video.VideoCapture
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.example.cameraxapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.camera.core.Preview
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import android.util.Log
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis
import androidx.camera.core.ImageCaptureException
import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy
import androidx.camera.video.FallbackStrategy
import androidx.camera.video.MediaStoreOutputOptions
import androidx.camera.video.Quality
import androidx.camera.video.QualitySelector
import androidx.camera.video.VideoRecordEvent
import androidx.core.content.PermissionChecker
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Locale

typealias LumaListener = (luma: Double) -> Unit

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private lateinit var viewBinding: ActivityMainBinding

    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null

    private var videoCapture: VideoCapture<Recorder>? = null
    private var recording: Recording? = null

    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(viewBinding.root)

        // Request camera permissions
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            requestPermissions()
        }

        // Set up the listeners for take photo and video capture buttons
        viewBinding.imageCaptureButton.setOnClickListener {
            takePhoto()
            //Toast.makeText(this, "buttonpressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            //Log.d(TAG,"button pressed")
        }
        //viewBinding.videoCaptureButton.setOnClickListener { captureVideo() }

        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }

    private val activityResultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions())
        { permissions ->
            // Handle Permission granted/rejected
            var permissionGranted = true
            permissions.entries.forEach {
                if (it.key in REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS && it.value == false)
                    permissionGranted = false
            }
            if (!permissionGranted) {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext,
                    "Permission request denied",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                startCamera()
            }
        }




    private fun takePhoto() {// Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return
        Toast.makeText(this, "inside takephoto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        // Create time stamped name and MediaStore entry.
        val name = SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US)
            .format(System.currentTimeMillis())
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/CameraX-Image")
            }
        }

        // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions
            .Builder(contentResolver,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                contentValues)
            .build()

        // Set up image capture listener, which is triggered after photo has
        // been taken
        imageCapture.takePicture(
            outputOptions,
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
                }

                override fun
                        onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults){
                    val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: ${output.savedUri}"
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d(TAG, msg)
                }
            }
        )}



    private fun captureVideo() {}

    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(viewBinding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
                }

            // Select back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector, preview)

            } catch(exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))}

    private fun requestPermissions() {
        activityResultLauncher.launch(REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS)
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CameraXApp"
        private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS =
            mutableListOf (
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
            ).apply {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                    add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                }
            }.toTypedArray()
    }

}
```

I was expecting when the "Take photo" button was clicked , am image would be taken and stored in the Pictures/CameraX-Image file. but there was not such images . I don't even know if the telephoto() function even works.

the app interface looks like this[image: app interface with the camera preview and a take photo button]

Comment: this repo can be helpfull: https://github.com/Coding-Meet/Camera-Using-CameraX

Comment: Where are you creating and binding the `ImageCapture` use case? From the provided code, it seems like your `ImageCapture` use case is never actually initialized and left as null, so `takePhoto` function will just return at first line. Also in your `startCamera` function, you are initializing and binding only the `Preview` use case, the `ImageCapture` use case is not added there.

Comment: @meet Bhavsar thank you i will try that too

Comment: @tahsin Masrur  problem is now solved thanks to your help